# Strange behaviour with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

In my C project I have this piece of code (a simple linked list):

```
while(current_node->v_uk <= version && current_node != NULL)
        current_node = current_node->next;
```

Well, this raises a segmentation fault, but, if I switch it to

```
while(TRUE){
        if(current_node->v_uk <= version && current_node != NULL)
                break;
        current_node = current_node->next;
}
```

it works as expected. I could not figure out what the problem may be

Comment: Why check `current_node != NULL` _after_ `current_node->v_uk`?

Comment: Both cases invoke UB ([undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)). One of many possible manifestations of UB is that "*it works as expected*".

Comment: Those two code snippets do no do the same thing. The first one ends the loop as soon as `current_node->v_uk <= version` is false, and if `current_node->v_uk <= version` is always true it will end in undfined behavior as it deferences a `NULL` pointer - you need to check if a pointer is `NULL` **BEFORE** you dereference it.. The second one ends the loop as soon as `current_node->v_uk <= version` is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which statements are evaluated inside the while condition is left to right. So **current_node->v_uk** is evaluated before the **current_node != NULL** check.

Swap those two around in your first code snippet.

EDIT: Thanks for the comments, just to make it clear: a logical AND operation, according to the rules of the C language, creates a sequence point where the arguments on the left are evaluated first, and then the arguments on the right. It is important to know that not all expressions are guaranteed to be evaluated left to right, but && is one of them. See here for more details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order

Comment: While in the OP’s code, the `while` condition contains an `&&` expression that is evaluated left side first, stating the order “inside the while condition is left to right” may mislead readers into believe that is a rule for `while` conditions, but it is not. For example, in `while (foo() + bar())`, `bar` might be evaluated first. This answer should state that the left operand of `&&` is evaluated first, and the right operand is only evaluated if the left operand is true. It should not state the order of evaluation inside a `while` condition is left to right.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yep, you are right, I will edit it. All operators are evaluated left to right in C.

Answer (score 1):

The both code snippets

```
while(current_node->v_uk <= version && current_node != NULL)
        current_node = current_node->next;
```

and

```
while(TRUE){
        if(current_node->v_uk <= version && current_node != NULL)
                break;
        current_node = current_node->next;
}
```

invoke undefined behavior because you are trying to access the data member `v_uk` without knowing whether  `current_node` is equal to `NULL` or not.

You have at first to check whether `current_node` is equal to `NULL` or not before trying to access the data member `v_uk`.

For example

```
while( current_node != NULL && current_node->v_uk <= version )
        current_node = current_node->next;
```

Answer (score 1):

the order of evaluation matters!! Logical expression are evaluated from left to right

This expression first dereferenced the pointer, then it checks if it is not NULL.

```
  while(current_node->v_uk <= version && current_node != NULL)
```

You need to:

```
while(current_node != NULL && current_node->v_uk <= version)
```

In C logical expressions are evaluated minimalistic short circuit way. So if current_node is null the whole expression is false and the second part of logical expression will not be evaluated - no dereferencing of NULL pointer .